# Confused about padding on top of label inside table

Tags: html, css

My code is similar to as follows:

```css
table,tr,td {
  border-collapse:collapse;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
label {
  font-size: 0.7rem;
}
table {
  table-layout: auto;
}
```

```html
<table>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <input>
      </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>
        <label>Foo bar</label>
      </td>
    </tr>
  </tbody>
</table>
```

The issue occurs when the element on top is bigger than the element on the bottom. I know the solution seems obvious: use `table-layout: auto;` However, as you can see, that doesn't work.

There is no padding or margin, and the height is not set manually on either of them. **My question is as follows: Why is the space there, and, more importantly, how can I remove it?**

Comment: From what you provided it is impossible to answer your question, as what you provided does not display what you describe. Unless you find a way to provide a [mcve], chances are nobody will be able to help. In other words, you are applying CSS rules to your `<label>` that you have not included in your question.

Comment: Note most browsers apply a `border-spacing:2px` to `<table>` elements. `table{border-spacing:0;}` removes it. This might be the mysterious space you're referring to.

Comment: I think that the spacing is due to the HTML renderer making the table rows the same height; But I thought `table-layout: auto;` was supposed to fix this.

Comment: [`table-layout`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/table-layout) specifies the algorithm used to set the width of your table's columns. It does not influence `height`. The provided link shows how different settings apply to an example (just click on the white boxes).

Comment: You need to give your label `display: block` (or flex) and set the `padding` to 0 on td.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I feel really stupid now: it was just the `line-height` property. I set it lower and that fixed it.

Edit: A more simple solution suggested by VilleKoo is to set the `display` property of the `<label>` to `block` or `flex` (setting the `padding` to `0`, which is mentioned in the comment, is not required)